# Retrieve special tags from Azure push notification

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I am working on developing an app for iOS, but at the moment I am not having a MAC, so I am using a Mac in the sky.

For the app I have to use push notifications, and I am trying to implement the solution for Azure seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started).

But I have to retrieve special information from the Push Notification like an ID

```
public override void DidReceivePushNotification(MSNotificationHub notificationHub, MSNotificationHubMessage message)
{
   var myAlert = UIAlertController.Create(message.Title, message.Body, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
   UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(myAlert, true, null);
}
```

Can I somehow retrieve the data from the push notification and hide it in the alert, as I have to use it, when the user press the alert.

I think the Push Notification is going to look like

```
{
   "aps":
   {
      "title":"Hello",
      "body":"Body"
   },
   "ID":"123"
}
```

Comment: According to your description, you want to specify the exact format of the notifications it wants to receive.Please take a look:[Notification Hubs templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-templates-cross-platform-push-messages)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT No, I am not trying to create a template, as I have no problems sending to both Apple and Android. 
I just miss some documentation regarding GetDictionaryOfValuesFromKeys & ValueForKey & ValueForKeyPath - for how to access ID in the example

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?